# Can not record iPhone screen from OSX

Tags: iphone, ios, quicktime, video

Why am I not able to record screen of my iPhone. Others can do it. iPhone has iOS 8, Mac has Yosemite.

Here I can see `Christoper's iPad` on one of my computer, but not on my other Mac.

[image]

Comment: Could you do a little editing. 1) Is your iPhone connected to the same computer? 2) Does this persist after restarting both the phone and the computer? There's the beginning of several possible questions here, but without some basic troubleshooting, people answering have to fill in the guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a bug in QuickTime Player. It recognizes both of my iDevices, but not a couple of family member's iDevices. All I could say is try updating the iPad to iOS 9, in the event that it's the iPad acting up.